# Spring security logoutSuccessUrl to login?logout seems to be protected although login page permitted to all

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the following Spring Security setup.
Note that a successful logout goes back to the login page again.

```
    http
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
```

I can login and logout with this setup. 
However the logout ends up on /login instead of /login?logout.

And when I login again it then goes to /login?logout.

So it seems the /login?logout seems to be protected.... despite the login page is permitted to all.

Any ideas how to solve this?

**EDIT**

As Bart suggested I tried to add an AntMatcher for login?logout like:

```
    http
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/ogin?logout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/app/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/login?logout").permitAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/app/login")
            .failureUrl("/app/login?error")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/app")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/app/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/app/login?logout")
```

but it gives the same behaviour. Note I tried to add it before and after protecting all /** sources.

Answer (score 4):

Have being faced with the same problem it works for me now using the following code:

```
http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll();
```

(i.e. adding the `.permitAll()` is the crucial part)

Answer (score 1):

I am dealing with the same problem. I further discovered, that, while `/login?logout` triggers a redirect to `/login`, `/login?error` does not.

That's kind of weird.

You can try that easily by manually entering the URL in the browser. Calls with different URL-params than `error` will all lead to being redirected to `/login`, and the param `error` being the sole exception (leading to `/login?error`).

My solution will be, I simply move the `/login` from the protected area.

E.g. instead of:

```
http.antMatcher("/user/**")
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/user/login")
                .authenticationDetailsSource(authenticationDetailsSource())
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/user/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
```

I use now:

```
http.antMatcher("/user/**")
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/userlogin")
                .authenticationDetailsSource(authenticationDetailsSource())
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/user/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
```

Comment: I agree with your workaround `.loginPage("/userlogin")` it works because you  have `.antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")` it won't work for `.antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")`.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*I know this type of problems puts a big question mark and makes to scratch the head by thinking **WHY***?

*Even though this thread has suggested possible workaround. But not the correct solution and reason. Because suggested workaround's can't display logout success/session expired message. As this thread is 5 year old and doesn't have solution this forced me to write answer here.*</sub>

**So, The Solution will be.**

```java
http
.csrf()
    .disable()
.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll() //Solution
    .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
    .and()
.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .failureUrl("/login?error")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
.logout()
    .logoutUrl("/logout")
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");
```

**Want to know why?**

<sub>**From previous configuration**</sub>

Your resource `/login` is restricted resource and it will be allowed only if
`authenticated = true` and `hasRole = "User"`
Whenever logout is made (or if you use in your logout success handler you are invalidating session and redirect) to `/login?logout` page but `/login` is a restricted resource so `FilterSecurityInterceptor` will redirects to the login page configured `.loginPage("/login")`. Hence you will not receive any param's passed in query string and logout success message will not be displayed.

And spring security is configured to store previously accessed resource in case of session expires, and after login it will redirects to previously attempted page which is `/login?logout` this will end up in again logout after login.

**Hence the solution will be always making login page as unrestricted resource.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the URL `/login?logout` is protected indeed. Spring Security will save the request to `/login?logout` and send you to the login page. After login it will send you back to the saved request.

Adding the rule should give access to the logout target page.

`http.antMatchers("/login?logout").permitAll();`

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tired but gives same behaviour; I edited the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This code in your config permit only for "USER", and all uri under `/app/*` have same requirement

```
.antMatchers("/app/**").hasRole("USER")
```

But your logout uri is

```
.logoutSuccessUrl("/app/login?logout")
```

Spring security work based on [springSecurityFilterChain](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html). Thats why you cannot access to logout uri.